# laravel query update with multiple condition

Tags: php, laravel

I have column named `flag` and I want to update it if value is `1` to `null` and if value is `null` to `1` so far is easy to update this column but issue comes where I send multiple data to controller and not only one.

## code

```
public function flagmultiplemessage(Request $request){
  $ids = $request->input('ids');
  DB::table('messages')->whereIn('id', $ids)
  ->whereNotNull('messages.flag')->update(['flag' => null])
  ->whereNull('messages.flag')->update(['flag' => '1']);
}
```

with function above i get:

```
message Call to a member function whereNull() on integer
```

## dd

code above is something like this:

```
ids = [11, 12, 3]
database = [
  11->flag = 1,
  12->flag = null,
  3->flag = 1,
]
```

the result of code above most change my database like:

```
database = [
  11->flag = null,
  12->flag = 1,
  3->flag = null,
]
```

**any idea why i get error?**

Comment: In your 'whereNotNull('messages.flag')->update(['flag' => null])' update() method return Boolean (1 or 0). You try to query on 1 or 0. that's why your errors shown.

Comment: @Md.SukelAli is there anyway i get null instead of 0?

Comment: In this way i don't think it's possible Because you wanted to query on a returning value and update method always give you Boolean(1 or 0) . You can wait maybe someone give you a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it occurred because you called `whereNull` method on `update` method.
You should run 3 separate query like this.

```php
public function flagmultiplemessage(Request $request){
  $ids = $request->input('ids');

  DB::transaction(function () use ($ids) {
    DB::table('messages')->whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->whereNotNull('messages.flag')->update(['flag' => 0]);

    DB::table('messages')->whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->whereNull('messages.flag')->update(['flag' => 1]);

    DB::table('messages')->whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->where('messages.flag', 0)->update(['flag' => null]);

  });

}
```

but for better performance I suggest you use boolean for flag column and use this simple query

```php
DB::table('messages')->whereIn('id', $ids)->update(['flag' => DB::raw('!flag')]);
```

Comment: hi, thank for the answer. your solution has extra process however it seems the only one to work with small change, it should have ` use ($ids)` in function like `DB::transaction(function () use ($ids) {`. I will wait for others if they want to edit their answers and I can get what I want with less process if not I'll accept yours. Thank you.

Comment: yea you are true , I forgot `use ($ids)` , Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for the error is that the `update()` method is not **chainable**

Alternatively, You can do the update in one query by using the mysql Case statement.

```
public function flagmultiplemessage(Request $request) {
    $ids = $request->input('ids');
    DB::table('messages')->whereIn('id', $ids)
        ->update(['flag' => DB::raw('case when flag is null then 1 else null end') ]);
}
```

Comment: hi, i'm getting `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ']'

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
DB::table('messages')->whereIn('id', $ids)->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('messages.flag')->update(['flag' => null])
                  ->orWhereNull('messages.flag')->update(['flag' => '1']);
        })
```

Comment: it says `Call to a member function orWhereNull() on integer`